# visibilitychange doesn't behave as intended

Tags: javascript

The MDN page for visibilitychange states that "it is fired when the content of a tab has become visible or has been hidden". However, when I run the following snippet, I immediatly get an infinite chain of alerts, so it is apparently being fired constantly. Why is this happening?

```js
function doEverything() {
    if(document.visibilityState == 'visible') {
        alert(document.visibilityState);
        document.removeEventListener("visibilitychange", doEverything());
    }
}

document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", doEverything());
```

Comment: Clearly I didn't read carefully enough and missed the "infinite chain of alerts".  So glad I just click on buttons without thinking about what they'll do :)

Comment: Well, my guess about the reason was way off the mark. Should I rename the question, since it's not actually related to the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are calling the function instead of passing it as argument.

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", doEverything);
```

and

```
document.removeEventListener("visibilitychange", doEverything);
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Why** is this happening?

**The reason is because you are constantly executing the `doEverything` function in a never-ending loop.**

1) `doEverything()` is first executed here:

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", doEverything());
```

2) `doEverything()` goes into a loop here, constantly displaying the `alert`:

```
function doEverything() {
    if(document.visibilityState == 'visible') {
        alert(document.visibilityState);
        document.removeEventListener("visibilitychange", doEverything());
    }
}
```

The above can be seen as the equivalent of:

```
function doEverything() {
    if (true) {
        doEverything(); // loop
    }
}
```

**To fix this, you don't want to execute the function but rather provide the reference of the function. It's a simple change from `doEverything()` to `doEverything` in your `addEventListener()` and `removeEventListener()`:**

```
function doEverything() {
    if(document.visibilityState == 'visible') {
        console.log('hi');
        document.removeEventListener("visibilitychange", doEverything);
    }
}

document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", doEverything);
```

This will run the alert only once when the tab is switched.